# SQL: select distinct on column1 and sum up column2 values of merged rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

How could one achieve to get sums of column values regarding tags in a second column?

```
tag1  1000
tag1  2000
tag2  1000
tag3  1000
tag2  3000
tag1  1000
tag3  1000
tag3  1000
tag2  2000
tag3  2000
```

The required result looks like this

```
tag1  4000
tag2  6000
tag3  5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` on the tag column with `sum`

```
SELECT tagColumn, sum(tagValue) as TotalCount
FROM Table1
GROUP BY tagColumn
```